# How to request all the information from the HTML form in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

Suppose we have a form with multiple input elements say there are N of the:

```
<form>
    <input type = "text" name="1">
    <input type = "text" name="2">
           *         
           *
    <input type = "text" name="N">

</form>
```

How to get all the input elements in this form all at once and then just loop through them and process in some way?
I alwayse use `self.request.get("name")` to get the single element,but I coudn't find the method to get them all at one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# An iterable with alll items in the MultiDict:
# [('check', 'a'), ('check', 'b'), ('name', 'Bob')]
self.request.POST.items()
```

If you use webapp2: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#post-data